# Join on different named columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes in Pandas

```
left = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": ["A0", "A1", "A2"], "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2"]}
)

right = pd.DataFrame(
    {"C": ["A0", "A1", "A2"], "D": ["D0", "D2", "D3"]}
)
```

How would I left join on the column `A` in `left` dataframe and column `C` in `right` dataframe?

Output

```
B   D   A
B0  D0  A0
B1  D2  A1
B2  D3  A2
```

Comment: what is desired output? column A B D? make it text or image plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge` with kwargs `left_on` and `right_on`:

```
pd.merge(left, right, how="left", left_on="A", right_on="C")
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  A0  D0
1  A1  B1  A1  D2
2  A2  B2  A2  D3
```

Edit: you can drop the `C` column with `.drop("C", axis=1)`